# CSS not been applied to html page when opened through nodejs localhost

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a normal index.html page which has certain jquery,css,func while browsing in browser. However when I browse through nodejs localhost, nothing has been added to the page. What am I doing wrong?

[image: localhost:8000]
[image: index.html normal]

```
 var http= require('http');
 var fs=require('fs');

function onRequest(req,res){
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
fs.readFile('../index.html',null,function(err,data){
if(err)
{
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.write('File Not Found');
}
else{
    res.write(data);        
}
    res.end();  
});


 [![enter image description here][1]][1]}

 http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Where is your css file located?

Comment: make your css folder static or define the rout for css files

Comment: inside css/style.css, added in link tag in index.html..

Comment: I think this answer could be helpful [Simple node.js server that sends html+css as response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822034/simple-node-js-server-that-sends-htmlcss-as-response)